# How to link usb ethernet adapter to the specific ethenet adapter in Linux Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ethernet

I connected 4 USB-to-Ethernet adapters to my machine which runs Ubuntu 20.04.5.

When I check ifconfig, I see 5 network adapters, which is correct. eth0 is always native Ethernet adapter which installed in my machine. Also there: eth1, eth2, eth3, eth4.

But the problem is, every time I reboot the machine, these 4 Ethernet adapters are randomly assigned to different USB-to-Ethernet. In my case, I need them to be statically linked, for example I want that eth1 will always be linked to USB-to-Ethernet connected to the specific USB port on my machine, etc.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: The typical way to fix this is to configure udevd to assign each device a specific name.  Some distros have tools to assign network interfaces stable names automatically, but it may only happen during installation, and probably cant't work automatically for usb interfaces.

Comment: @user10489 can you please explain how to do that with udevd?

Comment: that would require research.  :-P  Also, it's a bit distro specific.  Maybe later.

Comment: Try https://askubuntu.com/questions/1317036/how-to-rename-a-network-interface-in-20-04   I certainly recommend using netplan, but I've never tried using it to name interfaces.